# How to call google play star rating dialog?

Tags: android, google-play, web-deployment

i am planing to insert a option like rate us in action bar and want to call google play star rating dialog.i know we can call our app page by using this concept. i search a lot but didnt find .Any help

```
Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(<packageName>);
        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
        startActivity(launchBrowser);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://www.androidsnippets.com/prompt-engaged-users-to-rate-your-app-in-the-android-market-appirater) piece of code. Eventually you can just use the following intent:

```
context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + APP_PACKAGE_NAME)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this piece of code:

```
String appPackage = mContext.getPackageName();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackage));
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Or for a complete and easy solution you can just add this library with gradle: https://github.com/fernandodev/easy-rating-dialog

```
compile 'com.github.fernandodev.easyratingdialog:easyratingdialog:+'
```